# antd Select fails lighthouse score: [aria-*] attributes do not have valid values

Tags: antd

I have a Select component in antd which fails the lighthouse score:

```
<input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_0_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_0_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_0_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_0">
```

> [aria-*] attributes do not have valid values

It also fails this:

> [role]s do not have all required [aria-*] attributes

It is defined like this:

const roles = [];
ROLES.forEach((role) => {
roles.push(<Select.Option value={role} key={role}>{role}</Select.Option>);
});

return (

{roles}

);

Whats wrong here?